# How does iPhone draw controller?

Tags: iphone, button, alphablending

I'm a newbie in iPhone development and now encounter a problem:

I want to add a small hotspot on a large image and simply came up with the idea that I can add a button in that area setting alpha 0 to hide the button. Unfortunately, the phone does not response click events any more. Instead, if I increase the alpha, I can receive click events without any problems. So I wonder in which order does iPhone draw controller on the screen. Is it because my background image is drawn after the button if I set alpha of button too low, so the click event is intercepted by the background image?

Any hints will be highly appreciated. Thank you all in advance!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button's style to Custom; the button will not be drawn, but should remain fully active.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo. But why simply setting the alpha value does not work?

Comment: Because the UI framework treats invisible buttons as inactive. A Custom button isn't invisible, technically speaking; it just doesn't draw itself. The purpose of "Custom" is so you can assign an image or override `drawRect:`, i.e., do your own custom drawing. But if you do neither, you effectively create a "visible" button that you can't see.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the order in which the views are drawn, it's rather that if a view's alpha is 0 it does not receive touch events. it's like the view is not there at all.

but you don't have to set the alpha to 0 on the UIButton, you can simply make it a Custom button instead of a Rounded Rect button. it'll be invisible and still work.

Comment: I tried again this time with alpha 0.01, it does not respond, either.